# How to foreach with blade in a controller passed variable (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I'm trying to **foreach in a php variable with blade**. I'm passing my variable to my view trought my controller but the view return me `Undefined variable`. I would like to know what's the right way to do this.

My Controller:

```
return view('pages.menu')->with([
    'someList' => $this->someList
]);
```

My View:

```
@foreach($someList as $item)
    @include('item.line', [
    'itemName' => $item->name,
    'itemValue' => $item->itemValue
])
@endforeach
```

Comment: Which variable is it saying is undefined?

Comment: $someList @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Try: `view('pages.menu')->with('someList', $this->someList)` or `view('pages.menu', [
    'someList' => $this->someList
])`

Comment: `return view('pages.menu')->with('someList' => $this->someList);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
As I cant delete, as the OP has accepted the answer, its now just speculative information based upon the docs. What your doing should work according to the source:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.5.28/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L177-L186

Thanks to @patricus for pointing this out:

> While the docs may not show that it is supported, you can pass an
>   array in the with() method. If you do, it is array_merged into the
>   current data set.

---

**Original Answer:**

From the docs, https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views

**You may pass an array of data to views:**

```
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);
```

When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs. 
Inside your view, you can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as  `<?php echo $key; ?>`.

As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the view helper function, you may use the with method to add **individual pieces of data** to the view:

```
return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');
```

---

So according to the docs, `with` may not support passing a single array, so you should change:

```
return view('pages.menu')->with([
    'someList' => $this->someList
]);
```

To:

```
return view('pages.menu')->with('someList', $this->someList);
```

or:

```
return view('pages.menu', [
    'someList' => $this->someList
]);
```

Comment: While the docs may not show that it is supported, you can pass an array in the `with()` method. If you do, it is `array_merge`d into the current data set. [Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.5.28/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L177-L186).

Comment: @patricus your right, added a note at the top as I cant remove it. Will do once the OP removes the accept.

Comment: @MathieuAuclair Did it fix the issue by changing the code, if not please un accept so I can delete my answer.